# Pandas Drop an Entire Column if All of the Values equal a Certain Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have dataframes that looks like this:

```
df_one
        a     b     c
    0   dave   blue   NaN
    1   bill   red    NaN
    2   sally  green  Member
    3   Ian    Org    Paid

df_two:

        a     b     c
    0   dave   blue   NaN
    1   bill   red    NaN
    2   sally  green  Member
```

The logic I am trying to implement is something like this:

```
If all of column C = "NaN" then drop the entire column 
Else if all of column C = "Member" drop the entire column 
else do nothing
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Added Expected Output

Expected Output if using on both data frames:

```
df_one
        a     b     c
    0   dave   blue   NaN
    1   bill   red    NaN
    2   sally  green  Member
    3   Ian    Org    Paid

df_two:

        a     b    
    0   dave   blue 
    1   bill   red 
    2   sally  green
```

Edit #2: Why am I doing this in the first place?

I am ripping text from a PDF file into placing into CSV files using the Tabula library.

The data is not coming out in the way that I am hoping it would, so I am applying ETL concepts to move the data around.

The final outcome would be for management to be able to open the final result into a nicely formatted Excel file.

Some of the columns have part of the headers put into a separate row and things got shifted around for some reason while ripping the data out of the PDF.

The headers look something like this:

```
Team     Type     Member    Contact
                   Count
```

What I am doing is checking an entire column for certain header values. If the entire column has a header value, I'm dropping the entire column.

Comment: What is expected output? Do you need remove rows or columns?

Comment: Columns, edited post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Idea is replace `Member` to missing values first, then test if at least one no missing value by `notna` with `any` and add all columns with `True`s for mask by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
mask = (df[['c']].replace('Member',np.nan)
                 .notna()
                 .any()
                 .reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=True))
print (mask)
```

Another idea id chain both mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
mask = ((df[['c']].notna() & df[['c']].ne('Member'))
                  .any()
                  .reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=True))
print (mask)
```

Last filter by columns in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, mask]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Yop, give em a sec.

Comment: Edited my original post to explain my purpose. It's super late right now, so I'm going to call it a night and will continue later.

I will post my results later. Thank you!

Comment: "List" object has no attribute "replace", but when I run type(df), it shows up as a dataframe, so that's weird.

Comment: @LunchBox In my anwer is not used list, so it seems some data related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = ['a','b','c']
d = [
['dave',   'blue',   np.NaN],
['bill',   'red',    np.NaN],
['sally',  'green',  'Member'],
['Ian',    'Org',    'Paid']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d,columns = c)
df2 = df1.loc[df1['a'] != 'Ian']

print (df1)
print (df2)


if df1.c.replace('Member',np.NaN).isnull().all():
    df1 = df1[df1.columns.drop(['c'])]
print (df1)

if df2.c.replace('Member',np.NaN).isnull().all():
    df2 = df2[df2.columns.drop(['c'])]
print (df2)
```

Output of this is:

```
       a      b       c
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
3    Ian    Org    Paid
       a      b       c
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
       a      b       c
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
3    Ian    Org    Paid
       a      b
0   dave   blue
1   bill    red
2  sally  green
```

Answer (score 0):

my idea is simple, maybe it will help you. I wanna make sure that you want this one: drop the whole column if this column contains only NaN or 'Member' else do nothing.

So I need to check the column first (contain only NaN or 'Member'). We change 'Member' to NaN and use numpy for a test(or something else).

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['dave','bill','sally','ian'],'B':['blue','red','green','org'],'C':[np.nan,np.nan,'Member','Paid']})
df2 = df.drop(index=[3],axis=0)
print(df)
print(df2)
```

```py
# df 1
col = pd.Series([np.nan if x=='Member' else x for x in df['C'].tolist()])
if col.isnull().all():
    df = df.drop(columns='C')
# df2
col = pd.Series([np.nan if x=='Member' else x for x in df2['C'].tolist()])
if col.isnull().all():
    df2 = df2.drop(columns='C')
print(df)
print(df2)
```

```
       A      B       C
0   dave   blue     NaN
1   bill    red     NaN
2  sally  green  Member
3    ian    org    Paid
       A      B
0   dave   blue
1   bill    red
2  sally  green
```